# Should I include paginated results in my sitemap.xml?

Tags: optimization, pagination, sitemap

I have listing pages that take a page argument on the url like the following:

```
http://www.domain.com/foo/bar/?page=7
```

Should I just include the URL without params or should I list all pages in my sitemap.xml?

#### EDIT

Paginated content are listings, like an index. Therefore their content is also (in more detail) found in detail pages. But these paginated ones are the only way to reach detail pages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I really wanted to find you a reliable source for this one, but I couldn't. Which means you'll have to make do with my intuition:

If the articles exist only in their paginated form, and you want them to be indexed as separate pages, *list them all*. They'll all have distinct content on them, so you won't be penalised for duplication.

I found details of one exception; [including page 1 twice](http://www.ragepank.com/articles/the-pagination-issue/). Basically you need to choose whether the first page will be /foo/bar/?page=1 or just /foo/bar/, then do a 301 redirect from the version you don't want to use.

Hope this helps (even just a little).

Tom

Comment: I shouldprobably have mentioned that the paginated resources are listing pages that link to detail pages. Thus containing links to detail pages.

Comment: Maybe then I'd omit the listing pages altogether. Doesn't sound like they have any real content on them and it could detract from the details pages - which is presumably where you actually want your users to go.

Comment: After reading your answer and the linked page, I started to realize that. I'll include only the first pages of listings maybe, but not all paginated results. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

**NO!**: You should add Meta-Tags to you paginated sites. This helps google to understand your pagination system.

**Example:**

On **page 1** you would add into `<head>`:

```
<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=2" />
```

On **page 2** you would add:

```
<link rel="prev" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=1" />
<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=3" />
```

On **page 3** you would add:

```
<link rel="prev" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=2" />
<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=4" />
```

And on **page 4** you would add:

```
<link rel="prev" href="http://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=3" />
```

See this document: [Pagination with rel=“next” and rel=“prev”](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.at/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html)

Comment: This, whilst useful, doesn't answer the question.. Even with the addition of meta tags the question still stands.

Comment: This is no longer a ranking signal, according to the link you made.

Comment: rel=next and rel=prev are deprecated https://twitter.com/googlesearchc/status/1108726443251519489

Answer (score 0):

In this case the ?page=7 probably relates to the content management systems page. In you site map file you can add this. In the site map if you want each of these pages to be displayed in what ever uses this file yes you should add them.